# Why was a purely programming-related question not moved/closed?

Tags: discussion

I recently flagged this question: [Emit signal for GIO.DBusProxy in python?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/220522/emit-signal-for-gio-dbusproxy-in-python).

This is a question about programming with Python, GIO and DBus. This is a purely programming-related question, i.e. the OP is not trying to communicate with Unity or a specific application, but both nodes of the communication are custom programs. The question also contains very few details: essentially, the OP provided just a method signature.

In short, this question has nothing to do with Ubuntu and is also poorly written. It is very unlikely that somebody will ever answer it. Why wasn't the question moved to Stack Overflow?

[Other questions](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=[python]+closed%3A1) purely about Python programming were closed. They were closed because they were off-topic, not because they were duplicates or too vague. Here are a few examples:

- [How to convert the time.time() to normal datetime format in linux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157025/how-to-convert-the-time-time-to-normal-datetime-format-in-linux): the problem expressed in this question is clear, in fact it has a valid answer;
- [partial key value retrieval data structure python](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172115/partial-key-value-retrieval-data-structure-python): well written and has an answer. The question also contains this comment: *"As this programming question is not Ubuntu-specific in any way, it is probably off-topic for Ask Ubuntu"*;
- [Why am i getting an error SyntaxError : invalid syntax](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194557/why-am-i-getting-an-error-syntaxerror-invalid-syntax): contains an helpful snippet of code -- there's also an answer (which is wrong, but just because the question was edited later);
- [What's the best way to use python lxml to extract content of a tag?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183475/whats-the-best-way-to-use-python-lxml-to-extract-content-of-a-tag): the question is clear and contains an helpful snippet;
- [Python programming from scratch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166448/python-programming-from-scratch): this particular question is even directly related to Ubuntu and Quickly (though is too generic, and shows no research effort).

Please, don't misunderstand: I'm not trying to close every question which is not strictly related to Ubuntu. My aim is to bring quality to Ask Ubuntu: there are many unanswered questions here, and many answered questions do not contain *great* answers (i.e. well-written answers that contain all the most relevant solutions).

If we're going to accept purely programming-related questions, then we will have more unanswered questions and more incomplete answers. The reason is simple: most of the people who can answer such questions do not look at Ask Ubuntu.

I'd like to see the GIO/DBus question moved or closed not because I don't want to see such questions in Ask Ubuntu, but because I want to direct the OP to a place where his question will receive the attention it deserves and will hopefully receive a great answer.

Comment: The question is about dbus binding for python, dbus is realted to ubuntu so the question is ontopic here (also in stack over flow)

Comment: @Tachyons: well, also Python itself is related to Ubuntu. Then questions like [How to convert the time.time() to normal datetime format in linux?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/157025/how-to-convert-the-time-time-to-normal-datetime-format-in-linux) (and [many others](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=[python]+closed%3A1)) should not have been closed.

Comment: Bad example. I just read through the first page, and they are all either dupea, abandonex, or so vague "unicorns" would be a valid answer.

Comment: @jrg: agreed, but you should look only at questions related to Python _programming_, not questions about upgrades or about problems with Python applications. I've updated my question to include a few examples.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini and i've refuted them all with my answer. They might belong on SO, but they aren't awesome, so they aren't migration worthy.

Comment: @jrg: they haven't been moved, but they have been closed. The problem is not migrating vs. closing, the problem is: what makes the GIO/DBus question different from the other questions I have listed? Note that all the questions I have listed are off-topic but answerable, that particular question is not just off-topic, it's also unanswerable (because it doesn't contain enough details).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Golden rule of migrations:

## Don't migrate crap.

You only ever migrate awesome questions. So far, I've seen nothing that is awesome in that search.

And by awesome, I mean something that has 5+ votes, a few hundred views, etc. We don't have anything like that on the site, so they don't get migrated.

Comment: Don't migrate crap, close it.