# Are Qt questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are Qt questions on topic?

I ask because I get hassled for asking them, despite clearly being linked to Ubuntu, especially since unity is becoming pure Qt. I am very rarely hassled for QML questions, and on the occasion I was, FossFreedom told the closers to lay off.

I can't find any definitive answers on Meta, so that is the reason I ask.

Comment: Example questions?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/555416/are-qstrings-mutable

Comment: I, personally, would call that question off-topic. Qt as a framework is not specific to Ubuntu in any way unlike the Ubuntu specific Ubuntu SDK and writing Ubuntu apps using QML with Ubuntu libraries. This is a very generic Qt question and the community has made it clear they don't want generic programming questions.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to say that "Generic Qt Question" != "Generic Programming Question". I have asked many generic qml questions, and they all receive high quality answers without a fuss. There is an additional argument to be made in that Canonical wants ubuntu to be the goto developer platform. http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/developers + http://blog.didrocks.fr/post/Ubuntu-loves-Developers

Comment: And I would like to say QML != Qt, no more than JSP is the same as Java. Please clear up your terminology first.

Comment: Why is this question being downvoted?

Answer (score 5):

See: [Can we please ban unrelated programming questions?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/10317/can-we-please-ban-unrelated-programming-questions)

People still have different interpretations on what's relevant to Ubuntu and what isn't. [Your question there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/555416/are-qstrings-mutable), was probably right on the line. It is more of a question about the language (or toolkit here) and not an Ubuntu feature in it... That's what sways people in development questions.

I'll completely agree that this might not seem fair... We'll happily answer any question about an application just for *being* in Ubuntu, so why is a toolkit any different?! But there you go... You're not always up against the rules, you're up against people's interpretations of the rules.

Comment: Funny I thought I had linked that thread. I was definitely looking at it, because it promped my question. Why? Because of this line: `What is the correct way to use the "scroll-event" signal (on an indicator) for Qt? - On topic. It has to do with the indicators, clearly part of the Ubuntu system.`

Comment: Indeed. That's about how Qt interfaces with parts of Ubuntu. String mutability isn't. We can dance around but rules mean relatively little to how the reviewers feel about these topics.

Comment: This principle however did not apply in these cases: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9403600/ -- In fact; it is plausible that these qml questions attract developers to the ubuntu platform, who may otherwise be developing on windows or mac.

Comment: @Akiva - I'd be really careful trying to fight this particular battle.  There's already a markedly large amount of tension on the stack network about why AU even exists when we have UL and saying all SO questions are on-topic here would certainly only enflame the same sort of issue.  I just take what I get and enjoy the community that is here.

Comment: Ughh... not a fan of stack overflow. It is subtle, but if you can appreciate this; asking a qml question on SO is like asking how to program QML in the blackberry forums. The coding style is just different than what I am used to on Ubuntu, and this frankly goes for many other programming languages as well.

Comment: [Really?](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=qml), that said, I'm not the biggest fan of SO.  That doesn't mean I just get to change the scope of sites, because I like the community on one or the other better.  This part of the conversation isn't related to the answer, and should really be in chat...  not a set of comments.

Comment: Its not the community (Although they do lack the Ubuntu Code of Conduct, and I think it shows), its just the questions and answers that these are framed in. That said; your link proves my point from my perspective. The first question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523701/how-to-set-colors-for-listview-items-alternately-using-qml/13524646#13524646 really isn't the way I would do things in Ubuntu. Instead of Listview; I use `Repeater { delegate: Label {}}`, as that provides way better flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

I just put down the shotgun and the shovel on programming questions.  It has been kicked around many times, and it's really too tiresome for many users to want to judge it on a case by case basis.

My 2 cents:
We either allow programming questions or we don't.
It's not worth my time to sift through what they're asking.
[Just don't make the mitochlorions start killing my brain to spare me from reading your question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/557387/help-in-qt-for-beginners)
and
[Check SO before you ask](https://askubuntu.com/questions/536135/how-to-use-the-c-c-code-to-change-ubuntus-background/)

note:  Oli's answer got an upvote from me.

Answer (score -5):

We have an SE site called Programmers.  We need to flag it for Moderator as a migration to that site for ANY QT questions.  Since QT is a multi-platform API Library, it would be a considerable concept that it is off topic and has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Unless you actually are dealing with QT libraries in Ubuntu, it needs to get flagged and migrated over to Programmers SE.

Comment: This might surprise you but Qt questions would be off-topic on [programmers.se]. Take a look at their [help center](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).